# PLSQL Nonsense (?) Error PLS-00103 in Package and Package Body

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, pls-00103

I'm getting what I believe to be a nonsensical error for a procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE reg AS
    TYPE ref_cursor IS ref cursor;
    ...
    FUNCTION show_enrollments RETURN ref_cursor;
    PROCEDURE return_prereqs
        (param_dept_code IN prerequisites.dept_code%type,
        param_course_no IN prerequisites.course_no%type);
>   PROCEDURE enroll
>       (param_sid IN enrollments.sid%type,
>       param_classid IN enrollments.classid%type,
>       err_msg OUT varchar(76));
    PROCEDURE delete_student
        (param_sid IN enrollments.sid%type);
    ...
END;
/
show errors
```

The error I get for the package

```
 LINE/COL ERROR
 -------- -------
 31/23    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the
          following:
          := . ) , @ % default character
          The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.
```

And the error I get for the package body

```
 LINE/COL ERROR
 -------- -------
 328/23   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the
          following:
          := . ) , @ % default character
          The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.
```

This is the procedure in the package body

```
PROCEDURE enroll
    (param_sid IN enrollments.sid%type,
    param_classid IN enrollments.classid%type,
    err_msg OUT varchar(76)) 
IS...
```

Am I doing something stupid here? I can't see what's wrong and it's pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's `err_msg OUT varchar(76)` as there is no `VARCHAR` data type in Oracle but only a `VARCHAR2`.

Try:

```
PROCEDURE enroll
    (param_sid IN enrollments.sid%type,
    param_classid IN enrollments.classid%type,
    err_msg OUT varchar2(76)) 
IS...
```

See [SQL Data Types in the PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html#GUID-239A89A6-4CBC-46F5-8A6A-10E8B465B7E8) for further information.

Comment: I changed it to varchar from varchar2 when I initially got the error. Changing it back gave me some message about PROCEDURE being replaced by static or something. I rolled it back to when it was working and re-implemented the additions, and it seems to be working now. Thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 1):

Hello there Please remove the size from the procedure as following:

```
  PROCEDURE enroll
       (param_sid IN enrollments.sid%type,
       param_classid IN enrollments.classid%type,
       err_msg OUT varchar2);
```

here i have change name also but you can keep yours

With size:

[image]

After removing size:

[image]